# struct and properties

Tags: c#, properties

I have a struct

```
namespace lib
{
    public struct strct_Test
    {
       int a;
       string b;
    }
}
```

Some where else i am doing

```
using lib;

class one
{
    private strct_Test var;

    public strct_Test Var
    {
       get {return var;}        // or should it be like return var.a; return var.b;
       set {var = value;}       // or should it be like var.a = value; var.b = value
    }
}
```

So can anybody guide whats the correct approach here as mentioned in the comments with the code ?

Comment: You realize that `return var.a; return var.b;` is quite different from `return var;` in a sense that one returns values from the object and the other returns the whole object?

Comment: Your question is unclear, because your first type is useless - it has private fields which nothing accesses. You *couldn't* use `var.a` from class `one`. Additionally, I'd strongly advise you to start following C# naming conventions, learn about automatically implemented properties, and avoid calling *anything* `var` (which is a contextual keyword)

Comment: it depends on what you want to do with your propertie ... will it be a part of your UI (Binding) or will some other Class use your setter to set a structur

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type of the property `Var` is `strct_Test`.

That means that the getter and setter should be using that type, as you have in your code.

Doing otherwise would cause a compilation error.

Answer (score 1):

**Ask your self what do you want to do**

**you should think do i need some of that values directly?**
so write Properties for each value you use (*not for all you have*)

**will i be replace the whole struc from an other class?**
so write Property for your struc

Answer (score 0):

The *correct* approach depends on how you would like your code structured.

In your example you define immutable property of type . `strct_Test`, so if you
you do something like this:

```
var o = new one(); 
o.Var.a = 10; 

var x = o.Var; 

//x.a != o.Var.a;
```

Hope this gives an idea of the behavior of your code, so you can decide if it's the best architecture for your concrete case.